# How to get the ids of selected slides

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

I need the ids of the slides that the user has selected in the left pane.

In the image below it would be 1 and 3.

Is there a method I can use or do I need to loop through all slides and check some property?

[image: PowerPoint 2013 Slide Pane]

**Update:** Solution based on Steve Rindsberg's VBA solution.

```
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide sld in Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange)
{
  int s = sld.SlideNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do it like so in VBA

```
   Dim oSl As Slide
    For Each oSl In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        Debug.Print oSl.SlideID
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks, that got the ball rolling :)